# How customize the validators alerts in jsGrid?

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I can not find a way to customize validator alerts in jsGrid. I can change the validation rule, but I need to use a custom function and remove the alert.

Also I can not find a reference to the **Invalid data entered!** Message, which is the default in the `required` alert.

I tried to follow some tips from some topics in github, I also followed the documentation to use `invalidNotify`, but without success.

I'm trying using a custom function, which besides validating already makes some changes in the layout to notify that the inserted data is invalid.

However, the standard jsGrid alert keeps popping up, as below:

```
fields: [{
            name: "sensorNumber",
            title: $('#title_meter_number').val(),
            type: "number",
            validate: function(config) {
                if (config == undefined) {
                    __validateRefuelling(config);
                }
```

Comment: The error is probably caused by a missing closing `]`.

Comment: @OldGeezer I did not just post the entire structure of the fields, because it was extensive, thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it with `invalidNotify`, I had used it erroneously before, it follows my code:

```js
var xxx = function() {
    $('#xxx').jsGrid({
        height: '250px',
        width: '100%',
        inserting: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        invalidNotify: function(args) {
            $('#alert-error-not-submit').removeClass('hidden');
        },
        fields: [{
            name: "sensorNumber",
            title: $('#title_meter_number').val(),
            type: "number",
            validate: "required"
        }, {
            name: "liters",
            title: $('#title_liters').val(),
            type: "number",
            validate: "required"
        }, {
            name: "measuredValue",
            title: $('#title_indication_of_the_meter').val(),
            type: "number",
            validate: "required"
        }, {
            type: "control"
        }]
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify "Invalid data entered!",you can add `invalidMessage` in your code,I tried it works

```js
$("#grid").jsGrid({ 
        height:"auto",
        width:"100%",
        autoload:true,
        editing:true,
        paging:true,
        invalidMessage:"your error msg",
        ...
        }
```